# Error: Page Control jump twice with single page swap

Tags: ios, swift, pagecontrol

With the following code, the page control has jumped twice instead of once during a single page swap. I need to add the `UIPageViewController` as subview as below, how can I make the pagecontrol act right? Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    let pagesArray = ["Page1ViewController", "Page2ViewController","Page3ViewController"]
    let pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(100, 600, 200, 20))


    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier (pagesArray[index])
        return vc
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController:UIPageViewController,
        viewControllerBeforeViewController
        viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{

            if var index = pagesArray.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!){
                if index > 0 {
                    index--
                    self.pageControl.currentPage = index
                    return viewControllerAtIndex(index)
                }
            }
            return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController:UIPageViewController,
        viewControllerAfterViewController
        viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{

            if var index = pagesArray.indexOf(viewController.restorationIdentifier!){
                if index < pagesArray.count - 1 {
                    index++
                    return viewControllerAtIndex(index)
                }
            }
            return nil
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyPageViewController")
        {
            self.addChildViewController(vc)
            self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
            self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

            pageViewController = vc as! UIPageViewController
            pageViewController.dataSource = self
            pageViewController.delegate = self
            pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(0)!], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have the page view controller on the storyboard, why do you instantiate it within another view controller?

Comment: Cos I will do a login checking later, if the user have not login, the root view controller will bring him to the orientation pages (UIPageViewController). If the user have already logged in, the root view controller should bring him to the main content page.

Comment: And I want the page control (those dots indicator) on top of everything. So I do the pages in addSubView way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? 
{

     let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier

     self.index = self.identifiers.indexOfObject(identifier!)

     if index == identifiers.count - 1 {
          return nil
     }

     //increment the index to get the viewController before the current one
     self.index = self.index + 1

     return self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)

 }

 func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? 
 {

      let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier

      self.index = self.identifiers.indexOfObject(identifier!)

      if index == 0 {

           return nil
      }

      //decrement the index to get the viewController before the current one
      self.index = self.index - 1

      return self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)

 }

  func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int 
 {
        return self.identifiers.count
 }

  func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int 
 {
        return 0
 }
```

Comment: Thank you and I tried. Is that I need to declare 'self.index' and 'self.identifier' somewhere first? They cannot be recognised within the function.

Comment: @AAC yes the self.identifiers will be array of your identifiers in your case it will be self.pagesArray

Comment: @AAC and there is no need to declare index globally.I created global variable to keep track of my current index. In your code you have used local declaration of index.

Comment: Excuse me. Where should I put 'pageControl.currentPage=index' after index value changed then? I have put into 'viewControllerAfterViewController' & 'viewControllerBeforeViewController' function. This made the highlighted dot in page indicator (the pageControl) jumped twice when I just swipe the page once. This is the problem I am facing. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Or should I, by any mean, try to detect the page swiping is done or success, then change the value of 'pageControl.currentPage'?

Comment: Can you set pageControl.currentPagr = index in   viewControllerAtIndex ?

Comment: I have tried to add "pageControl.currentPagr = index" in viewControllerAtIndex. (I tried to add in 'before and after function' before) But the same error happens - when I mousedown on page1, highlight dot change from 1st to 2nd. When page swiping done and I do mouseup, highlight dot change from 2nd to 3rd. Thanks again to your kindly help!

Comment: try to replicate my code of delegate functions? have you tried it?

Comment: Dear Sir, I did tried to copy and paste ur code into viewcontroller.swift but there are some error and cannot run. This is the project file: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qrpm2vp3bmj856/pageVC3.zip?dl=0

So I tired to combine ur code into mine:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/89oh49l3ufc2x4r/pageVC4.zip?dl=0
Then the code can run but the very beginning problem remain.
Thanks!

Comment: Will check and let you know

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about 'snippet...'. Type of coding style?